# Opening a website on iPad also opens other random websites

Tags: ipad

I use a website called [UkuTabs](https://ukutabs.com) which tells me the chords for songs.

Every-time I go to the website on my iPad, it always pops up with this random scam website which tells you that you will earn a lot of money. Even if I click cancel, it will take me there anyways. It won't even let me tap the back button. I don't know if this is a virus, but it never happens on my phone or computer.

Answer (score 1):

I tested that web site and nothing happened. Granted it was on Firefox and Mac High Sierra.

May I suggest in your case usually cleaning Safari history does the trick.

Here is what [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201265) says how to do that.

> Delete history, cache, and cookies
>
> Here's how to clear information from your device:
>
> To clear your history and cookies, go to Settings > Safari, and tap Clear History and Website Data. Clearing your history, cookies,
>   and browsing data from Safari won't change your AutoFill information.
>   To clear your cookies and keep your history, go to Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data, then tap Remove All Website Data.
>   To visit sites without leaving a history, turn private browsing on or off.
>
> When there's no history or website data to clear, the setting turns
>   gray. The setting might also be gray if you have web content
>   restrictions set up under Content & Privacy Restrictions in Screen
>   Time.